# Creating a new column in R that looks at the data from two previous columns and assigns a Factor level?

Tags: r

I have a Data set that looks at the two parasites of snails I want to create a New column that states whether the snails have No parasites "None", Type 1 "TYPE1",Type 2 "TYPE2" or both parasites "DUAL".

```
   Block Weight Parasite1  Parasite2
1      1   1.23        1           1         
2      1   3.14        1           1         
3      1   2.55        1           0         
4      1   2.67        0           1         
5      1   3.36        0           1         
6      1   3.16        0           0         
7      1   3.41        0           1         
8      1   2.47        0           1         
9      1   1.56        0           1         
10     1   2.66        1           1
```

I have thought of using if or if else but i can't seem to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do with a few if else statements, but this is easier I think

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="row Block Weight Parasite1  Parasite2
1      1   1.23        1           1         
2      1   3.14        1           1         
3      1   2.55        1           0         
4      1   2.67        0           1         
5      1   3.36        0           1         
6      1   3.16        0           0         
7      1   3.41        0           1         
8      1   2.47        0           1         
9      1   1.56        0           1         
10     1   2.66        1           1")[,-1]


within(dat, {
  type <- interaction(Parasite1, Parasite2, sep = '')
  type <- factor(type, levels = c('11','10','01','00'),
                 labels = c('DUAL','TYPE1','TYPE2','None'))
})

#    Block Weight Parasite1 Parasite2  type
# 1      1   1.23         1         1  DUAL
# 2      1   3.14         1         1  DUAL
# 3      1   2.55         1         0 TYPE1
# 4      1   2.67         0         1 TYPE2
# 5      1   3.36         0         1 TYPE2
# 6      1   3.16         0         0  None
# 7      1   3.41         0         1 TYPE2
# 8      1   2.47         0         1 TYPE2
# 9      1   1.56         0         1 TYPE2
# 10     1   2.66         1         1  DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df$NewCol <- c('None', 'TYPE1', 'TYPE2', 'DUAL')[with(df,
                   as.numeric(factor(1+2*Parasite1+4*Parasite2)))]

df
#   Block Weight Parasite1 Parasite2 NewCol
#1      1   1.23         1         1   DUAL
#2      1   3.14         1         1   DUAL
#3      1   2.55         1         0  TYPE1
#4      1   2.67         0         1  TYPE2
#5      1   3.36         0         1  TYPE2
#6      1   3.16         0         0   None
#7      1   3.41         0         1  TYPE2
#8      1   2.47         0         1  TYPE2
#9      1   1.56         0         1  TYPE2
#10     1   2.66         1         1   DUAL
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L), Weight = c(1.23, 3.14, 2.55, 2.67, 3.36, 3.16, 3.41, 2.47, 
 1.56, 2.66), Parasite1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L), Parasite2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Block", 
 "Weight", "Parasite1", "Parasite2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```